# Prediction of errors by type and previous count per day

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, prediction

I have the following time-series dataset:

```
         time  error  count
0  2021-10-03   1111      2
1  2021-10-03   2222      4
2  2021-10-03   3333      6
3  2021-10-03   4444      2
4  2021-10-03   5555      8
```

I created a class error_type with attributes 'time', 'error' and 'count' and then insert these classes to dictionary where key is time (date of occurrence) and value is the object with mentioned attributes.

So the dictionary looks like:

```
time (2021-10-03) 
 - class with error (1111) and count (2)
 - class with error (2222) and count (4)
.
.
.
time (2021-10-04) 
 - class with error (3333) and count (6)
 - class with error (4444) and count (2)
.
.
.
```

I have data for several months and they look as follows:

[image]

What I would like to accomplish is go through dictionary and predict count of errors in total for the next day by error type so we know how many errors we can expect next days and what type we could expect.

I am confused with the time-series here and tried to apply ARIMA model just for prediction of error counts which did not work well. I tried to change weekends where there are lower numbers to rolling mean, delete those days where no error happened but it did not help ARIMA to give accurate prediction.

Comment: Hard to say what methods would work well without knowing the more about the time series. I would try some simple methods first, like persistence (guess the error counts of the previous day) mean (guess the average grouped by error type). If the counts change slowly enough, that may be the best you can do. If there's trend or seasonality in the time series, ARIMA might help. Can you add some context to the question? What kind of errors are you predicting? How are past error counts related to future error counts? Do you expect seasonality and trend to be present?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I edited my question and added data plot which could help to see the character of my time series data.

Comment: Looks like you've got weekly seasonality. Have you tried adding a multiplicative seasonality term of period 7 to the ARIMA time series?